# MySQL compare two tables and return rows that have the same primary key but different data in other fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two structurally identical tables, table2 is a staging ground for new data that will be used in bulk updating table1.

I need to find out which rows would be updated in table1. I want to ignore those rows that would be inserted and those that would be deleted. I'm just interested in the updated rows, where the primary key stays the same but one or more of the other fields in the row contains different data.

So far the closest I have come is the following statement.

```
SELECT table2.* FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON table1.primarykey = table2.primarykey
WHERE table1.field1 != table2.field1
OR table1.field2 != table2.field2
OR table1.field3 != table2.field3
```

This returns 0 rows.

EDIT: The query actually works. There was a problem with the data itself. I'm going to go facepalm for a while.

Thank you everyone for your input.

Comment: As Conrad was getting at, null does not equal null so you have to take that into account in your comparison - the way you have it written, the data may be "the same" but will show up as not equal if there are nulls in there.

Comment: Also, if you are using a storage engine that allows it, why not just turn off autocommit, run the update and see what changed, then roll it back?

Comment: @Poodlehat: This is a nice idea but how will you "see" what changed?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what exactly you need to do. If its offline, I just save off two csv files and view them in my comparison tool of choice... but then you wouldn't need this query, now would you? :)

Comment: I will have to take the nulls into account as I didn't know about that. However, I have stripped my query down so there is no where clause and the inner join doesn't appear to be joining all matching rows.

Comment: *"the inner join doesn't appear to be joining all matching rows"*. What are the datatypes of the `Primary` keys of the 2 tables? Are they the same or different?

Answer (score 4):

One thing that your not accounting for is nulls. This may or may not be your problem as it depends on the data

```
SELECT table2.* FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON table1.primarykey = table2.primarykey
WHERE table1.field1 != table2.field1
      OR table1.field2 != table2.field2
      OR table1.field3 != table2.field3
      OR (table1.field1 is null and table2.field1  is not null)
      OR (table2.field1 is null and table1.field1  is not null)
      OR (table1.field2 is null and table2.field2  is not null)
      OR (table2.field2 is null and table1.field2  is not null)
      OR (table1.field3 is null and table2.field3  is not null)
      OR (table2.field3 is null and table1.field3  is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

In other words you want to count in table2 how many rows have a primary key the same as in table1 and at least one of the fields different, right? But how is it important if the data is different or not? If data is the same, the UPDATE would have no effect.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(T2.*) 
FROM
   table2 AS T2
JOIN table1 AS T1 ON (T1.primarykey = T2.primarykey);
```

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question, maybe you didn't read the entire question? jumped the gun a little there